# Resolving "null comparison" bug in SonarQube while testing equals()

Tags: java, null, sonarqube, equals

SonarQube is throwing me a major bug in my quality code reports:

> Remove this call to "equals"; comparisons against null always return false; consider using '== null' to check for nullity.

However, this `equals` call is a overrid one, which means I would like to test what happens if my object is actually null inside the `equals()` method.

Is there any workaround to this issue ? Should I not test the nullability of my object, or have I no other choice but to ignore this case ?

---

**EDIT** The code as asked in the comments:

The object itself:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MyTestedObject other = (MyTestedObject) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (type != other.type)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Inside the test:

```
@Test
public void test()    {
    MyTestedObject testedObject = new MyTestedObject();

    boolean nullValue = testedObject.equals(null);
    Assert.assertFalse(nullValue);
}
```

Comment: Show us your code. Otherwise we only can guess.

Comment: Do you mean that SonarQube complains about a code in the unit test? In this case it is ok to suppress/ignore it.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is not worth the effort to remove one single issue. Better take it as such and go on.

Comment: The [rule which generates this issue](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2159) should not be run against test code. I suppose that your SonarQube analysis is not set up correctly. Are you using Maven to run the analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SonarQube is telling you that you have a bug in your code. Contract for `equals` if well-defined in [java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return false.

If you are doing it differently in your override - you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Idk why this is a good Answer? The test will test indeed the "For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false." rule...the "should" is here the key word. So I would suppress the warning for this test in Sonarcube. Question was how? Can somebody write the suppress warning what works?

Comment: I guess the question was edited afterwards, so answer is not too relevant now, when I was answering I did not know that the bug was reported in a test code. It is not very good idea to run Sonar on a test code. As for your question - I could suggest using `assertThat(testedObject, not(equalTo(null)))` or similar. Or in modern java there is a `record` so you don't need to worry about `equals` implementation.